# Is it RESTful to have PUT request overwrite record with different primary key?

Tags: postgresql, rest, server, routes, restful-architecture

I have a situation where in my PostgreSQL database I have a `user` table with this row:

```
{ 
  id: 1
  name: 'unique name here'
}
```

where `id` is a primary key and `name` has a unique constraint.

If I were to do a `PUT /users/2` request to the server connected to this DB and with a request payload below:

```
{ 
  name: 'unique name here'
}
```

that has the same name, it would delete the row with `id` of `1` and create the row with `id` of `2` using an upsert function.

Using RESTful architecture, is this proper or should the database be left alone and the server return a status code like `409` indicating that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.

Answer (score 0):

As far as RESTfulness is concerned, there's nothing to prohibit PUT from overwriting existing data and/or having side effects (as long as it's idempotent of course), and implementation details about the underlying data are outside the scope of REST, so in that sense, either solution you proposed is fine.

However, deleting the old one and creating a new one with a new primary key feels like a strange implementation to me. **Remember, following the guidelines of RESTful design does not guarantee that you'll end up with a sensible implementation of your server application!** That's up to you.

Of course without knowing the details of your application it's impossible to say for sure what the best way is, but I think I'd lean towards disallowing this request - let the client do a PUT to the correct URI.

A word about the status code though: it wasn't clear from your question if users/2 already exists in this example. As you say, a 409 indicates a conflict with the *current state* of the resource, so it's not appropriate for rejecting a request to create a new resource.

I think I'd use either a 400 Bad Request or a 403 Forbidden in that case.